# A question about convergence in Sobolev space $H^s(\mathbb{R}^n).$

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Consider the Sobolev space defined by Fourier transform $H^s(\mathbb{R}^n):=\{u \in \mathcal{S}': \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} (1+|\xi|^2)^{s} |\hat{u}(\xi)|^2 d\xi <+\infty \}.$ Here $\mathcal{S}'$ means tempered distribution. Now consider a sequence of distribution $u_n \in H^{s+2}$ satisfying that $u_n \rightarrow u$ in $H^s(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and $\nabla u_n \rightarrow \nabla u$ in $H^s(\mathbb{R}^n),$ and $\Delta u_n \rightarrow f$ in $H^s(\mathbb{R}^n),$ can we deduce that $u \in H^{s+2}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and $\Delta u=f$?

If $s$ is an integer, the Sobolev space coincides with the traditional Sobolev space defined by the weak derivative, then it is obvious that the above statement is true via testing smooth compactly supported functions.

My attempt is, since $\widehat{\Delta u_n}=-|\xi|^2\hat{u}_n(\xi),$ then we have
$$
 \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} (1+|\xi|^2)^{s} |-|\xi|^2\hat{u_n}(\xi)-\hat{f}(
\xi)|^2 d\xi \rightarrow 0.
$$
We also know that
$$
 \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} (1+|\xi|^2)^{s} |\hat{u_n}(\xi)-\hat{u}(
\xi)|^2 d\xi \rightarrow 0, \qquad  \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} (1+|\xi|^2)^{s} |\xi|^2||\hat{u_n}(\xi)-\hat{u}(
\xi)|^2 d\xi \rightarrow 0.
$$
Then how can I deduce that $\hat{f}=-|\xi|^2\hat{u}(\xi)$?

Comment: Convergence in $H^s$ implies Convergence in $D'$ (or $\mathcal{S}'$), so $u_n \to u$ in $D'$, and therefore $\Delta u_n \to \Delta u$ in $D'$, so $f = \Delta u$.

Comment: Yes, now the question becomes: if two distributions are the same, and one of them is in $H^s,$ then the other is also in $H^s.$ It may be an idiot question but indeed has bothered me for a long time. Since $H^s \subset \mathcal{D}',$ so the equivalence in a bigger space can deduce that they are equal in its subspace?

Comment: It is a foundational matter to show that the inclusion $H^s \to D'$ is injective and continuous. The case $s = 0$ is well known, and it is easy to derive the general case using the Fourier transform.